# Rbind() doesn't work with character data with different names

Tags: r

I have tried to add a row to an existing dataset which I read into R from a csv file.

The dataset looks like this:

```
         Format PctShare
1      NewsTalk     12.6
2       Country     12.5
3  AdultContemp      8.2
4        PopHit      5.9
5   ClassicRock      4.7
6    ClassicHit      3.9
7   RhythmicHit      3.7
8    UrbanAdult      3.6
9      HotAdult      3.5
10 UrbanContemp      3.3
11      Mexican      2.9
12    AllSports      2.5
```

After naming the dataset "share", I tried to add a 13th row to it by using this code:

```
totalshare <- rbind(share, c("Others", 32.7)
```

--> which didn't work and gave me this warning message:

```
Warning message:In`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Others"):invalid factor level, NA generated
```

However, when I tried entering a row with an existing character value ("AllSports") in the dataset with this code:

```
rbind(share, c("AllSports", 32.7))
```

--> it added the row perfectly

I am wondering whether I need to tell R that there is a new character value under the column "Format" before I bind the new row to R?

Comment: or you can `levels(share$Format) <- c(levels(share$Format), 'Others')` and then `rbind` since no other answers keep your data as factors

Answer (score 2):

Your `format` columns is a `factor` variable. Look at `str(share)`, `str(share$format)`, `class(share$format)` and `levels(share$format)` for more information. The reason `rbind(share, c("AllSports", 32.7)` worked is because `"AllSports"` is already an existing factor level for the `format` variable.

To fix the issue, convert the `format` column to `character` via:

`share$format <- as.character(share$format)`

Do some searches on `factor` variables and setting factor levels to learn more. Moreover, when you are reading in the file from csv, you can force any character strings to *not* convert to factors with the option, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` -- for example, `share <- read.csv(myfile.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks @JasonAizkalns! This helped a lot. After adding the row to the table, I noticed the second table, which I named totalshare, has the PctShare column changed to characters as well! I had to change it back to numeric with as.numeric before I could draw a barplot. Just a little observation in case anyone else has similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Two solution I have in mind

Solution 1:-
before reading data

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
```

or
Solution 2:-
as suggested by @JasonAizkalns